# Automate production of PDFs containing tables in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, pdf, jupyter-notebook, pyfpdf

I'd like some inspiration for procedures or modules that could make my life easier..

My issue is that I have numerous separate Jupyter Notebooks, that performs different heavy computations. At the moment, I spend a lot of time copy pasting the outcome of these separate Jupyter Notebooks into a couple of tables in LaTex, that I finally export as a PDF.

I'd like to minimize the manual work by automating the copy-pasting steps. Are there any ways to  automate the production and exportation of tables into PDFs in Jupyter Notebook? I have looked at PyFPDF myself.

Are there any alternatives to this?

Thanks in advance to this awesome community!

Comment: It looks like PyFPDF will work for the export step. I haven't used that package though. I like using ReportLab for Python-based production of PDF. The upstream step could probably be done using nbformat to extract what you want to combine with the LaTex. Search 'nbformat' at [the Jupyter Discourse Forum](https://discourse.jupyter.org/) to find code using it to iterate on cells in notebooks. Several of the posts will describe it & have links to resources about nbformat, too.

Comment: You can print the table as Pandas DataFrame in the notebook and export the notebook as a PDF file.  There is a framework called [Mercury](https://github.com/mljar/mercury) that can be used for scheduling notebooks and automatically exporting executed notebooks to PDF. You can read more in the article on [automated PDF reports with Python and Mercury](https://mljar.com/blog/automated-reports-python/).